# How to count duplicate tags in a string of many tags

Tags: php

I have a photo list page where each photo has multiple tags (as spaced words). I'm trying to display most of the tags on the page after:

- Removing duplicate tags
- Sorting tags by having most occurring tags first

The code looks like this:

```
$tags1 = "red blue green yellow colors";
$tags2 = "blue green grass tree garden";    
$tags3 = "pink blue colors paint sky"

addTags($tags1);
addTags($tags2);
addTags($tags3);
echo (processTags());

private $tagsArray;
public function addTags($param) {
    if($param == ""){ // no tags
        return;
    }
    $explode = explode(" ",$param);
    $this->tagsArray = array_merge($this->tagsArray, $explode);
}

private function processTags(){
    $processedTags = array_count_values($this->tagsArray);
    arsort($processedTags);
    $count = 0;
    foreach($processedTags as $tag => $value) { 
        if(++$count>50) break; // don't print more than 50 tags
        $output .= "<a href=\"/tags/$tag\">$tag</a>";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Each photo can have dozens of tags and there can be hundreds of tags total. Is there any way to improve the code to make it more *efficient*? Could it be done with less code? The above code works just fine, but I'm just curious to know if there is a better way to go about it.

Comment: Since your code runs and is functional, this question might be better suited to the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site rather than Stack Overflow.  And thanks for doing a good job on the formatting.

Comment: Will post there, thanks.